# How o selecting the letter(capital small letter) in the jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a text box,

in that text box i have some data example

`Apple,apple,Bat,boll,Cat,Dog`...

when i type A it displays `Apple,apple` list  and `apple` list.(i.e. it displays **two** list)

so i codded to allow **one** list i.e.(`Apple,apple`)

**update**

```
            var character = causeFirstLetter;
           if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
                   $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9;font-size:20px' align='left' >"+causeFirstLetter+ "</label>"+"</li>"+"<hr style='border:1px solid #EBEBEB'/>");
    }
```

now my problem is when i type small letter "a" it wont allow.How to rectify this problem?

Comment: Why you use `.toUpperCase()` function?

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question. Second, could you provide a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: If you need to show words that starts with needed char, you could better to don't use `.toUpperCase()` function.
`var character = causeFirstLetter;
           /*  and you ever don't need this check  if (character == character) {
                }*/`

Comment: i need to display the capital letter and small letter  depends user typing

Comment: What is causeFirstLetter? is that character the user types? Or the first letter of each row in your data sample. The real question here is why did both 'Apple, apple' and 'apple' show up when you typed 'a'. The code that handles this is not shown. Share the code that does the filtering of the data sample and creates the list.

Comment: Yes my friend! Even better would be if you could recreate the problem you are facing on this site: http://jsfiddle.net ... You can paste only the relevant html/css/js. If your html is being created by some server side tech, just paste the code you see in the browser's view source. If you can provide us a live example of how its not working, then we can tinker and guide you to the solution.

Comment: i created and paste my account .how to publish the code.just update is enough?

Comment: The site (jsfiddle) has a share button. Clicking on that gives you three different urls. The first one I think is a direct link. Share that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13452/discussion-between-user1324068-and-amith-george)